# Is it possible to take slow-mo video in high resolution on Galaxy S5?

Tags: video-recording, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Just discovered that I can take slow-mo videos (8x slowdown) on my Galaxy S5. It is wonderful. However resolution is, softly speaking, bad. Guess because it wants to save memory. But I have 128gb micro SD, so I *almost* don't care about my memory ;-)

Is it possible to take slow-mo in max (3840x2160) resolution instead of just 1280*720?

Comment: I expect not: 8x slow-motion means it has to encode eight times as many frames of video per second, and write those frames to the SD card, so that means the limit on pixels-per-frame is an eighth as much. The limit is caused by the rate of production, not the size of the end product.